# Pandas ignoring leading space in specific row when reading CSV

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am reading a CSV in Pandas as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(
    "sample.csv",
    dtype = {'token':str},
    keep_default_na = False
)
```

You can see that one of its columns is `'token'`, which I'm reading in as string type. When I open `sample.csv` in a text editor, the 20851th line has `'token' = ' 29'` (note the leading space). However, when I do `df.loc[20851,'token']`, Python outputs `'29'` without the leading space. I don't know why this happens. When I read a different row that has a leading space, e.g. `df.loc[30118,'token']`, Python correctly outputs `' 66'` with a leading space.

I tried manually setting `df.loc[20851,'token'] = ' 29'` and saving the CSV. Reading it again still gives the same error. If I manually set it to have 2 leading spaces, i.e. `df.loc[20851,'token'] = '  29'`, and then save it and read it again, I get a single leading space as desired. I don't know why this happens.

I've also tried various options in the `read_csv()` call such as `encoding = 'utf8'`, `skipinitialspace = False` and `delim_whitespace = False`, but the result is unchanged.

Comment: What are you after - leaving the spaces as is?

Comment: Yes, I want to leave the leading space in `' 29'` as is.

Comment: Without a [mre] it's pretty hard to suggest a solution to this problem

Comment: It is hard to help without the actual data. I would check maybe the first character is not space but TAB (/t) or some other character.